# Matlab Plotting responses of transfer function to arbitrary input without using step function

Tags: function, matlab, transfer

I am trying to plot the response of a transfer function to an arbitrary input. The step response can be plotted as shown below.

```
T = tf(164.6,[1 13 32 184.6]) 
step(T)
```

The step response plot is a plot of the inverse Laplace of 1/s * tf(164.6,[1 13 32 184.6]), but trying to plot this directly without the step function using the command

```
syms s
T = tf(164.6,[1 13 32 184.6]) 
fplot(ilaplace(1/s*poly2sym(T.Numerator{:},s)/poly2sym(T.Denominator{:},s)))
```

generates a blank plot. Is there a way
to plot the response directly without using the step function that would allow you to plot the response to any input?